# C# OrderBy does not offer sort by DateTime

Tags: c#, sorting

I am starting with C# programming. I would like to ask you for help.
I have a list of files from one directory. I would like to sort these files by date of creation/modification.

part of code:

```
List<string> _f = new List<string>();
string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(_p);
foreach (string _fi in _files){_f.Add(_fi);};
_f.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Created, y.Created))
```

Problem is that ".Created" does not exist. I was not able to find any relevant parameter which can be used to sort by DateTime. Could you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `FileInfo` class

Comment: The variable `_f` contains only strings, not `FileInfo` instances.

Comment: perfect, thank you for information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `FileInfo` class

```
   var _files = Directory
     .EnumerateFiles(_p)
     .Select(file => new FileInfo(file))
     .OrderBy(info => info.LastWriteTime) 
     .Select(info => info.FullName)
     .ToArray(); // If you want to get files' names as an array
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I added following code to my program: foreach (string it in _files){Console.WriteLine(it);}. Problem is that files are sorted by name and not by creationtime. Sorry if it is trivial, but I am newcomer.

Comment: @cotablise: Please, check what file's time you actually want: `CreateTime` (creation) or `LastWriteTime` (last modification)

Comment: yeah, you are right. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Note: the last projection (`.ToArray()`) is either exactly what you need, not quite what you need (`.ToList()` perhaps) or _not needed at all_.

Comment: Thank you for additional info.